# Local Storage in Dart Flutter

Tags: dart, local-storage, flutter

I have now tried the package shared_preferences for the operation of the local storage.

my question is :

how do I use local storage in the flutter socket io? What is the recommended package to use and how easy is it to be used?

Comment: https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite

Comment: About _What is the recommended package to use_: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: thank you for the explanation, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

localstorage requires that you await for the storage to become ready.

```
localstorage: ^4.0.0

Future<void> saveStorage(x, y, z) async {
await storage.ready;
storage.setItem('x', x);
storage.setItem('y', y);
storage.setItem('z', z);
}

Future<void> _extractFromStorage() async {
await storage.ready;
String x = storage.getItem('x');
String y = storage.getItem('y');
String z = storage.getItem('z');

 _foo(x,y,z);
}
```

...

```
 final LocalStorage storage = new LocalStorage('unique_identifier');
 saveStorage(_x, _y, _z);
```